# Java generics: capture generic type when copying instances of subclasses

Tags: java, generics

In the following code sample, is there a way to avoid the ugly SuppressWarnings annotations?

The code tests if parameter *t* is an instance of *A* and returns another instance of *A* if so. That satisfies the general contract of *createCopy()* to return an object of the same type as its parameter, so it is a safe operation. The same goes for the test for *B*.

I know about [Wildcard Capture and Helper Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html) but I'm not sure if and how that helps in this situation although the problem appears to be quite similar.

```
abstract class Base {
    public static <T extends Base> T createCopy(T t) {
        if (t instanceof A) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T copy = (T) new A((A) t);
            return copy;
        }

        if (t instanceof B) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T copy = (T) new B((B) t);
            return copy;
        }

        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}

class A extends Base {
    public A() { }
    public A(A a) { }
}

class B extends Base {
    public B() { }
    public B(B b) { }
}
```

Comment: if you think the annotations are 'ugly' just remove them. they are optional.

Comment: Then I get a type-safety warning. I want to know if there is a way to avoid this warning since the code _is_ type-safe. If just I were able to let the compiler know.

Comment: you let the compiler know by using the annotation.

Comment: By the way, why do you use a static method instead of a non-static, abstract method?

Comment: @WilQu, yes that works much better, thanks! (Coffee++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the class to the method, but that's still ugly:

```
abstract class Base {
    public static <T extends Base> T createCopy(final T t,
            final Class<T> klass) {
        if (t instanceof A) {
            final T copy = klass.cast(new A((A) t));
            return copy;
        }

        if (t instanceof B) {
            final T copy = klass.cast(new B((B) t));
            return copy;
        }

        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}

class A extends Base {
    public A() {
    }

    public A(final A a) {
    }
}

class B extends Base {
    public B() {
    }

    public B(final B b) {
    }
}
```

Calling `t.getClass()` doesn't work either. The reason is that T can be a subtype of A or B (that's why you code is not really type-safe).

**EDIT** :
Why your code is not really type-safe: imagine a class `AA` that extends `A`. If you call your method with an instance of this class, it will create an object of type `A` and try to cast it to `AA`.

Comment: Interesting answer but why do you think my code is not really type-safe? It returns an A for an A and a B for a B, doesn't it?

Comment: @devconsole, yes but it will fail for subtypes of A or B (see my edit)